# how to change the value of a text node using .contents()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML I have:,

```
<div>hello<span>hai</span></div>
```

And in that above structure, I just need to change the value "hello" to some other text, so I tried this:

```
$('div').contents()[0].value = "text"; //attempt 1
$('div').contents()[0] = "text"; //attempt 2
```

Can anybody suggest the right way to achieve what I want...?

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qmqgA/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue) property

```
$('div').contents()[0].nodeValue = "text";
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8uWHv/2/)

or

```
$('div').prop('firstChild').nodeValue = "text";
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8uWHv/1/)

Comment: +1 please link me to the relevant documents..  Thanks'

Comment: Its 5 min remaining to accept your answer, mean time can you tell what is `.prop('firstChild')` i have not heard of this before..? what's firstChild in this context..? is it a selector..? But doc says that prop can have argument which should be property..?

Comment: [firstChild](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Node.firstChild.html) is a property of a node object, using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method we can fetch the properties of an jQuery object so using `.prop('firstChild')` is the same as `$(...)[0].firstChild`

Answer (score 1):

Check this <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmqgA/1/)</kbd>

```
 $('div').contents()[0].nodeValue = 'test';
```

---

Another way you change specific string replace,

Check this <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmqgA/2/)</kbd>

```
$('div').contents(':contains("hello")')[0].nodeValue = 'test';
```

---

`$('#one').contents(':not(*)')` In this case text node selects non-element child nodes and the first node is the one we want to replace.

```
$('div').contents(':not(*)')[0].nodeValue = ' test ';
```

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmqgA/3/)**</kbd>

Hope this help you!